# Comparing pandas data frame columns and giving the same score to identical columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, comparison

Consider a `pandas` data frame containing 24 rows. I need to compare all columns and for columns who are identical give the same score.
For example, if column `A` is identical to column `C` and `F`, then they all should receive the score `1`.

Then if column `B` is identical to column `Z` then they will receive score `2`.
If possible, I wish that the scores will be presented as new columns at all rows.
So that if for example row `A` got the score `1`, then a new column `score_A` containing 24 rows will contain the number\string `1` 24 times, once for every row

I tried several strategies. They led to illogical results

Comment: Suppose `A` is identical to `C`, then `C` gets score 1. Later `C` gets tested against the other columns. Question 1: Shall `C` gets tested against the following columns or against all columns (from `D` on or from `A` on)? Question 2: If `C` is identical to say `D`, shall then the score 1 from `C` be replaced with score 2 or shall only `D` get score 2?

Comment: Hi Anna! Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: quick question: if A was in the same group as B, but not C, would C get the score of 2, or would it be 3?

Comment: C would get the score 2

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': [4, 5, 6],
    'c': [1, 2, 3],
    'd': [7, 8, 9],
    'e': [4, 5, 6],
    'f': [1, 2, 3],
    'g': [9, 10, 11]
})

seen = []
score = 1
for col in df.columns:
    if not col in seen: # if the column is new to us
        seen.append(col) # add it to the seen list
        df['score_'+ col] = score # then add the score of it as a column to the df
        for new_col in [c for c in df.columns if c not in seen]: # for every column that we haven't seen yet
            if df[col].equals(df[new_col]): # if it is the same as our current column
                df['score_'+ new_col] = score # then add a score column for it with the current score
                seen.append(new_col)
        score += 1

>>> df
   a  b  c  d  e  f   g  score_a  score_c  score_f  score_b  score_e  score_d  score_g
0  1  4  1  7  4  1   9        1        1        1        2        2        3        4
1  2  5  2  8  5  2  10        1        1        1        2        2        3        4
2  3  6  3  9  6  3  11        1        1        1        2        2        3        4
```

Comment: thanks for helping - I encountered a problems -  the same problem I encountered with my code that I tried, the result of the code is that all the columns are different from each other. And that's not the case, actually there is a lot of identity

Comment: sorry can you rephrase that for me? I don't follow

Comment: yes - the problem is that the result of the code is that all columns are different from one onother, even though thats not the case. for example - if columns A , B , C are the same and need to get the same score, they get a different score

Comment: so you're saying that my code doesn't work on your actual dataset? It might be simpler to provide an actual example from your data, and what you expect the output to be

Comment: I will present here a small sample from my data and the required result for it
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'set_1': [0.05, 0.05, 0.07, 0.15, 0.43, 0.2],
                        'set_2': [0.05, 0.05, 0.07, 0.15, 0.43, 0.2],
                        'set_3': [0.05, 0.05, 0.07, 0.15, 0.43, 0.2],
                        'set_4': [0.05, 0.05, 0.07, 0.15, 0.43, 0.2],
                        'set_5': [0.07, 0.07, 0.06, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
                        'set_6': [0.07, 0.07, 0.06, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
                       })
the result sould be = [1,1,1,1,2,2]

Comment: now the result is [1,2,3,4,5,6], instead of [1,1,1,1,2,2]

Comment: is it [1,2,3,4,5,6] or [1,1,1,1,2,2]

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone and thanks for the help. Found the reason why the code was not working correctly. The problem was in the data. After I rounded them to two digits after the period and converted them to a string, the problem was solved.